# Cannot edit fields in the backend

Tags: magento-1.7, product, edit

I have been editing product information on a daily basis using the Magento admin panel (Version 1.7.1) and have had no problems. However, all of a sudden while I am in edit mode editing a product, the fields become "uneditable"

What I mean is, I cannot click inside the fields (for example product description) to try to change it.

I am at loss what the problem is. I tried logging out and back in, and nothing works. Yet If I come back in a couple of hours, the system starts to work and I can edit information to my hearts content. Then after a few hours, same thing happens again.

Any ideas/suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not default Magento issue, it means there were any third party extension or customization is cause for this issue.

Kindly check the code when the filed is disabled, if any script is responsible for disabling the filed remove that part of code, one more trick kindly change the id and class of that filed and check it.