# Magento 1.9.1 - Unable to edit (click) URL Rewrite fields in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite, redirect, apache

I'm trying to edit (or redirect) some category menus to other categories. Example, I have two sub-categories called "Compression Wear" (id 60 - /compression-wear.html) AND "Compression Wear" (id 67 - /compression-wear-secondary.html). Each are under different parent categories, same store. I'd like to only add products to id 60 and have them appear in id 67 also. I figured the best route was to redirect id 60 to id 67 using URL Rewrite Management.

**Problem:**

After clicking to edit a URL Rewrite, I'm unable to click to edit any field except for "Request Path". I made a custom URL Rewrite but that did not redirect. I was able to click and edit the fields when I made my own Custom Rewrite, however, when and if I try to edit it after saving, same problem, I'm unable to click and edit fields. Screenshot and Code below.

[image: Unable to click to edit fields of URL Rewrite and related code from Inspect]

The code on the right for one of the paths I was trying to click and edit says, `title="Target Path" disabled="disabled"` if I change that to `disabled="enabled"` nothing happens, but if I remove it completely, I'm able to cursor over the text field and edit things. This of course is just in Chrome Inspector, so no real changes are being saved.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried reindexing, recaching, restarting apache, logging in Firefox, Chrome, IE - all to no resolution. I do believe at one point I was able to redirect just fine without this issue. I'm unaware if this is caused by an extension/module installed in Magento (or to go about finding if it is).

**Please help**

Is it possibly something to change on my server end, as I've been unable to find anything related to my problem, except for one "not really answered or followed-up" post. [Post found here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135040/cannot-edit-fields-in-the-backend)

Answer (score 0):

**Update from Original Poster:**

This was a dumb mistake on my part and I've resolved the issue. If the "Type" of rewrite is "System" it cannot be edited as this generated by Magento. I simply searched for the id of the category I wanted to redirect. In my case, id 67, and deleted the "System" rewrite. Then, I created a custom URL rewrite and like normally, I created the rewrite.

It may be due to my own error (lack of sleep/focus, and many tabs open) that I was trying to edit the "System" rewrite instead of the "Custom" one - which caused me to think the "Custom" rewrite was not editable as well.

Hope this helps anyone, if they make my same dumb mistake.

**Moral of the story:** "System" type rewrites are not editable.